# Why is my output different depending on how the variable len is defined?

Tags: c

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int len = 3; // length of word
    char * word = "cat"; // word to be sorted
    char sortedWord[len];
    int i, j, temp;
    // store chars from 'word' to an array 'sortedWord[]'
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sortedWord[i] = *word;
        word++;
    }

    // sort the array using bubble sort
    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
            if (sortedWord[j] > sortedWord[j + 1]) {
                temp = sortedWord[j];
                sortedWord[j] = sortedWord[j + 1];
                sortedWord[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", sortedWord);

}
```

The focus of this question is the variable 'len'. If I were to define len to be equal to 3, then the output is as expected (i.e. "act"). However, I want to be able to find the length without explicitly defining it.

I have tried to define len as:

```
int len = strlen (word);
```

However, the output is not as expected. It would give me results such as actW?, actX?, and so on.

This same behavior occurs when I try to define len as:

```
int len;
for (len = 0; *word != '\0'; len++) {
    word++;
}
```

Surprisingly, if I were to print the the variable len right after explicitly defining it, it would also behave the same way.

```
int len = 3;
printf("Length: %d\n", len); // will cause the output to be different
```

I am sure that I am missing a fundamental concept, but I am not sure on an approach to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `printf("%s\n", sortedWord);` --> `printf("%.*s\n", len, sortedWord);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Usually your one line hints are very useful, but you have to admit that this is very obscure!

Comment: It means that it doesn't need nul-char termination. BLUEPIXY hits the spot everytime I must agree with you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `storeWord` is not `null` terminated causing *undefined behavior*, add the `null` terminator and it will no longer behave erratically.

And also, if you increment the `word` pointer, it will end up pointing to the `null` terminator of the original string, so don't do that. Instead, use the index to access elements.

```
char sortedWord[len + 1]; // One more for the '\0'
int i, j, temp;
// store chars from 'word' to an array 'sortedWord[]'
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sortedWord[i] = word[i];
}
storeWord[len] = '\0';
```

One more thing, when writing pointers to string literals, use `const` to prevent accidentally modifiying them, since that is undefined behavior too, so

```
const char *word = "cat";
```

Comment: I would also be wary of incrementing an original pointer (`word`), instead of either incrementing a copy of it, or indexing it.

Comment: @WeatherVane or do `sortedWord[i] = word[i]`

Comment: Edit is better.